# When using a unified search/address bar within a web browser, how do you force the browser to search for a typed URL?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

In several web browsers (Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome being the two examples that I have seen this used in), rather than have separate search and address bars, these are combined into one - this means that, for example, you can either type "superuser.com" to visit the main Superuser homepage, or alternatively you could simply type "Super User" which would use the default search engine to search for the phrase "Super User".

So - my question. If you wanted to search for the "superuser.com" URL rather than visiting it, how would you go about this when using a unified search/address bar? Are there any queries or similar that can be placed before entries that force a search, rather than the web browser assuming that it should simply visit the URL in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I search for "superuser.com" rather than visiting the site?

Add a single quote `'` before the search string:

```
'superuser.com
```

Or enclose the search search string with double quotes `"`:

```
"superuser.com"
```

Examples:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]